# Steam-Login Flask infinite redirection loop

Tags: python, flask

**I want to make a steam-login flask, this is my first time trying it and I'm new to this thing.
When I run the code, it enters an endless redirect loop and give me this "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_openid import OpenID
import os
import re
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'

oid = OpenID(app, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'openid_store'))

STEAM_API_KEY = 'steam_api_key'
STEAM_LOGIN_URL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login'
STEAM_ID_REGEX = re.compile(r'(\d+)$')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if 'steam_id' in session:
        return 'Steam ID: ' + session['steam_id']
    return redirect(url_for('login', next=url_for('home')))

@app.route('/login')
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
    if 'steam_id' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return oid.try_login(STEAM_LOGIN_URL, ask_for=['nickname', 'email'])

@oid.after_login
def create_or_login(resp):
    match = STEAM_ID_REGEX.search(resp.identity_url)
    if match:
        steam_id = match.group(1)
        session['steam_id'] = steam_id
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return 'Invalid Steam ID'

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('steam_id', None)
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**loop look like this in terminal**

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2024 22:35:25] "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2024 22:35:27] "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2024 22:35:29] "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -